# Micronaut Data MonogDB Reactive Transactions

Tags: mongodb, reactive-programming, project-reactor, micronaut, micronaut-data

I am looking for guidance on implementation transactions when using Micronaut Data MongoDB (Reactive)

Below I have given code snippets from what I am trying to implement:

**Data dependencies included:**

```
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-mongodb")
implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-reactive")
implementation("io.micronaut.reactor:micronaut-reactor")
runtimeOnly("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams")
```

**Repository interfaces:**

```
@MongoRepository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends ReactiveStreamsPageableRepository<Department, String> {

}
```

```
@MongoRepository
public interface OrganisationRepository extends ReactiveStreamsPageableRepository<Organisation, String> {

}
```

**Transactional service method:**

In the below method, I have added `@Transactional` annotation. Within the method, I am calling two repository `update` operations. To combine them, I am using `zip` to subscribe for their completion and returning.

```java
@Override
  @Transactional
  public Mono<Boolean> updateCounts( final MessageDto message ) {
    // do something

    // update department reactive
    final Mono<Department> departmentUpdate = Mono.from( departmentRepository.findById( departmentId ) )
        .flatMap( department -> {
          // do something
          return Mono.from( departmentRepository.update( department ) );
        } );
    log.info( "Department update mono created" );

    // update organization reactive
    final Mono<Organisation> organizationUpdate = Mono.from( organisationRepository.findById( orgId ) )
        .flatMap( org -> {
          // do something
          return Mono.from( organisationRepository.update( org ) );
        } );
    log.info( "Org update mono created" );

    // zip and respond
    return Mono.zip( departmentUpdate, organizationUpdate ).map( tuple -> {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    } );
```

Exception:

```
11:22:22.635 [Thread-10] WARN  i.m.d.m.o.DefaultReactiveMongoRepositoryOperations - Rolling back transaction on error: Query failed with error code 251 and error message 'Given transaction number 2 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is 1' on server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 251 and error message 'Given transaction number 2 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is 1' on server localhost:27017
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.FindOperation$2.onResult(FindOperation.java:787)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CommandOperationHelper.lambda$transformingReadCallback$10(CommandOperationHelper.java:322)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:272)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:683)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:523)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:498)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:821)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:785)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:645)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:642)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:250)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:160)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:573)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$AsynchronousSocketChannelAdapter.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:118)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:642)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$600(InternalStreamConnection.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:775)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:760)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:645)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:642)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:250)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousChannelStream.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:221)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

From the exception, it looks transaction is being closed at MongoDB side even though application transaction is live. It might be because `ClientSession` of MongoDB is closed after the first update But I am not clear how to solve this.

I see that the below OOTB class has transaction implementation for reactive mode. So, I think transactions are supported in reactive mode as well. I am just not able to find the right way to use it.

**OOTB class where I find transactional related implementation:**

io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.DefaultReactiveMongoRepositoryOperations

Has anybody tried this and also is transaction supported in Micronaut Mongo Data Reactive Streams (Reactor Project)?

Comment: Which version of Micronaut Data do you use? It looks like a bug. Can you please create an issue?

Comment: Hi @Denis, Thanks for your response. I have now tried with both versions 3.8.1 and 3.9.6 (latest). I see same issue in both versions. I have raised an issue here: [2048](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/2048)

Comment: https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-mongodb-asynchronous-gradle-java.html

The guide says

Transaction mode is not supported when the synchronous transaction manager is created using Reactive transaction manager!

Comment: @Siddhivinayak Have you managed to implement it? Could you show an example? I'm having the same difficulty.